# CakePHP 2.9 + MongoDB Introduction

Tags: php, mongodb, cakephp

Am start connect to MongoDB with cake php. I have done cakephp2.2 with MongoDB but I need to connect to cakephp2.9 with MongoDB, I have complete all process and when and call to any controller it showing fatel error.

```
Error: Class 'String' not found
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\oncall\app\Plugin\Mongodb\Model\Datasource\MongodbSource.php
Line: 1476
```

Answer (score 0):

well, you just need to replace String with CakeText at line 1476 , as class String is deprecated in cake 2.9 > https://api.cakephp.org/2.9/class-String.html